# Read a XML tree structure recursively in a List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML file with besides other things the following structure.

```
<start something="1">
    <into intoSomething="1">
    <node nodeAtt="1"> 
        <thisChanges change="1"/>
    </node>
    <node nodeAtt="1"> 
        <thisChanges change="1"/>
    </node>
    <start something="1">
        <node nodeAtt="1"> 
            <thisChanges change="1"/>
        </node>
        <node nodeAtt="1"> 
            <thisChanges change="1"/>
        </node>
        <start something="1">
            <node nodeAtt="1"> 
                <thisChanges change="1"/>
            </node>
            <node nodeAtt="1"> 
                <thisChanges change="1"/>
            </node>
        </start>
        <node nodeAtt="1"> 
            <thisChanges change="1"/>
        </node>
        <node nodeAtt="1"> 
            <thisChanges change="1"/>
        </node>
    </start>
    <node nodeAtt="1"> 
        <thisChanges change="1"/>
    </node>
    <node nodeAtt="1"> 
        <thisChanges change="1"/>
    </node>
</start>
```

What would be the best method to read those into a List recursively in .net? There are other things in the XML file too but I will deal with those parts separately. I also want to just parse everything inside "node" into a string instead of reading its attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you expect? What is `T`?

Comment: What im trying to do is to read this into a nested structure then allow a user to edit the data in a table and then write it back out to a file. Which is why the <thisChanges> I want to be kept as a string to be able to edit it completely separately. 

The List<T> will save the start something="1"> inside that the children and inside those children any more children and so on so I can easily iterate over the structure and pull out the data for writing back to file.

Comment: What advantage do you expect from using a List over an XElement?

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a Composite pattern.

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx#_self1

Doing it with a list would require T to be some type that can be either another list or a node.

As for reading it in have you heard of the DOM?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It basically parses the xml into a data structure for you.  So you might be reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 0):

The way i would recommend is to implement `IEnumerable<T>` on an instance. The implementation would walk the tree in your xml and builds the `node` instances you are interested it.

Then just call `ToList` on it.

```
XDocument xmlFile = //use whatever source you like, doesnt even need to be an XDocument
TreeWalker walker = new TreeWalker(xmlfile);
var list = walker.ToList();
```

If you do use an `XDocument`, a really easy way to get all the `node` elements is [`XDocument.Descendants(XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will do all the 'tree walking' for you.